# Como faço para ler valores da URL em Javascript (QueryString)?

Tags: javascript, querystring

Quando acesso uma página, por exemplo

- `/item?tipo=1&nome=po%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20cura`

Como faço para pegar esses valores da URL, decodificando apropriadamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte método:

```
// parametro `a` opcional, ex: `tipo=1&nome=espada#custo=0`
// o valor padrão é da URL atual
function GetQueryString(a)
{
    a = a || window.location.search.substr(1).split('&').concat(window.location.hash.substr(1).split("&"));

    if (typeof a === "string")
        a = a.split("#").join("&").split("&");

    // se não há valores, retorna um objeto vazio
    if (!a) return {};

    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
        // obtem array com chave/valor
        var p = a[i].split('=');

        // se não houver valor, ignora o parametro
        if (p.length != 2) continue;

        // adiciona a propriedade chave ao objeto de retorno
        // com o valor decodificado, substituindo `+` por ` `
        // para aceitar URLs codificadas com `+` ao invés de `%20`
        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    // retorna o objeto criado
    return b;
}

// uso
var qs = GetQueryString();
```

Desta forma sua variável `qs` na URL

- `/item?tipo=1&nome=po%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20cura#tipo=2`

será

```
qs["tipo"];     // 2
qs["nome"];     // poção de cura
qs["nothere"];  // undefined (objeto)
```

Vale observar que neste método se houver mais de um parâmetro com o mesmo nome, somente o ultimo será considerado.

---

#### Método do Google

Abrindo o código do Google eu encontrei

```
function (b) {
    var c = typeof b === "undefined";
    if (a !== h && c) return a;
    for (var d = {}, b = b || k[B][vb], e = b[p]("?"), f = b[p]("#"), b = (f === -1 ? b[Ya](e + 1) : [b[Ya](e + 1, f - e - 1), "&", b[Ya](f + 1)][K](""))[z]("&"), e = i.dd ? ia : unescape, f = 0, g = b[w]; f < g; ++f) {
        var l = b[f][p]("=");
        if (l !== -1) {
            var q = b[f][I](0, l),
                l = b[f][I](l + 1),
                l = l[Ca](/\+/g, " ");
            try {
                d[q] = e(l)
            } catch (A) {}
        }
    }
    c && (a = d);
    return d
}
```

Esta minificado, mas é compreensível.

O código procura por `?` e `#` que é o ponto da URL em que os parâmetros aparecem. E para cada parâmetro eles dividem pelo `=` utilizando `indexOf`. Se o parâmetro tem valor eles adicionam ao objeto. No final o código cuida da decodificação e substitui `+` por .

---

Uma outra opção seria utilizar `Regex` para extrair os valores

Answer (score 8):

Para retirar informação do url você pode criar um objecto com pares de `chave:valor` de cada um dos parametros do url.

Neste caso, e uma vêz que o separador de parametros é o simbolo `&` os valores aqui presentes são:

```
tipo=1
nome=po%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20cura 
// "poção de cura" em versão está codificada para evitar caracteres não compatíveis com url, e evitar espaços brancos.
```

Assim, dependendo de que biblioteca você utiliza aqui ficam alguns exemplos:

Javascript simples:

```
function queryObj() {
    var result = {}, keyValuePairs = location.search.slice(1).split("&");
    keyValuePairs.forEach(function(keyValuePair) {
        keyValuePair = keyValuePair.split('=');
        result[decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[1]) || '';
    });
    return result;
}
var myParam = queryObj();
console.log(myParam);
```

Isto dá: `Object {tipo: "1", nome: "poção de cura"}`

Note:

- em javascript é preciso descodificar a string usando [**decodeURIComponent()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)
- uma vez que a query string começa com `?`, usei o método `splice()` para remover o primeiro caracter da string.

No caso de estar a usar uma versão antiga do IE, e não browsers que supportem o ECMAScript5, use esta versão, em vêz de `forEach()`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length; i++) {
    keyValuePairs[i] = keyValuePairs[i].split('=');
    result[decodeURIComponent(keyValuePairs[i][0])] = decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair[1] || '');
};
```

---

Usando uma biblioteca como [**Mootools**](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/String.QueryString), fica mais fácil. assim só é preciso:

```
var myParam = window.location.search.slice(1).parseQueryString();
//retorna também: Object {tipo: "1", nome: "poção de cura"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar um plugin jQuery: [jQuery plugin Purl](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)

Exemplo de uso:

1º Importar a bibiloteca:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<caminho>/purl.js"></script>
```

Para encontrar a bibliloteca basta copiar o código [purl.js](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl/blob/master/purl.js),criar um arquivo com o nome purl.js e colar;

2º Depois de importar a biblioteca você pode escolher fazer de duas maneiras:

Utilizando jQuery

```
var url = $.url('http://url.com.br/item?tipo=1&nome=po%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20cura'); 
var tipo = url.param('tipo'); // valor do tipo = "1"
var nome = url.param('nome'); // valor do nome = "po%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20cura"
```

Sem utilização jQuery

```
var url = purl('http://url.com.br/item?tipo=1&nome=po%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20cura');
var tipo = url.param('tipo'); // valor do tipo = "1"
var nome = url.param('nome'); // valor do nome = "po%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20cura"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function queryString(parameter) {  
              var loc = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);   
              var param_value = false;   
              var params = loc.split("&");   
              for (i=0; i<params.length;i++) {   
                  param_name = params[i].substring(0,params[i].indexOf('='));   
                  if (param_name == parameter) {                                          
                      param_value = params[i].substring(params[i].indexOf('=')+1)   
                  }   
              }   
              if (param_value) {   
                  return param_value;   
              }   
              else {   
                  return false;   
              }   
        }
```

uso

```
var id = queryString("id");
```

Answer (score 3):

Se quiser usar uma framework, como jquery por exemplo, pode usar um plugin como este:

https://github.com/promatik/jQuery-Dynamic-URL ([exemplo de utilização aqui](http://promatik.no.sapo.pt/github/dynamic-url/))

Permite-lhe fazer por exemplo:

```
$.getVars(); 
> {"tipo" : 1, "nome" : "poção de cura"}

$.getVars().nome; 
> "poção de cura"
```

E permite até alterar a barra de endereço adicionando os seus próprios parâmetros em runtime:

```
$.pushVar("genero", "medicina");
$.popVar("tipo");
```

O url ficaria:

```
/item?nome=po%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20cura&genero=medicina
```

Answer (score 3):

As funções apresentadas anteriormente tem um desempenho ruim. Eu implementei duas funções para isto que são respectivamente 35% e 120% **mais rápidas**, elas fazem parte da biblioteca [Ideal.js](https://github.com/webarthur/ideal.js):

```
// URL: http://exemplo.org/?nome=Arthur&sobrenome=Araújo
console.log(location.getQueryParam('sobrenome'))

// ou pode pegar todos os parâmentros de uma só vez:
var params = location.getQueryParams()
console.log('Nome', params['nome'])
console.log('Sobrenome', params['sobrenome'])
```

Função 1 - location.getQueryParam():

```
window.location.getQueryParam = function(name, query) {

  if (!query) {
    query = window.location.search
  }

  var l = query.length
  var n = '' // name
  var v = '' // value
  var t = false

  for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
    var c = query[i]

    if (c==='=') {
      t = true
    }
    else if (c==='&' || i===l-1) {

      if (n==name) {
        return decodeURIComponent(v)
      }

      t = false
      n = ''
      v = ''
    }
    else if (i>0 || c!=='?') {
      if (t) {
        if (c==='+') {
          c = ' '
        }
        v += c
      }
      else {
        n += c
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Função 2 - location.getQueryParams():

```
window.location.getQueryParams = function(query) {

  if (!query) {
    query = window.location.search
  }

  var l = query.length
  var q = {} // query
  var n = '' // name
  var v = '' // value
  var t = false

  for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
    var c = query[i]

    if (c==='=') {
      t = true
    }
    else if (c==='&' || i===l-1) {
      t = false
      q[n] = decodeURIComponent(v)
      n = ''
      v = ''
    }
    else if (i>0 || c!=='?') {
      if (t) {
        if (c==='+') {
          c = ' '
        }
        v += c
      }
      else {
        n += c
      }
    }
  }
  return q
}
```

Você pode ver a diferença do desempenho no meu [teste de caso](https://jsperf.com/querystring-with-javascript-tutz/1).

Answer (score 3):

Procurei esta mesma questão no fórum em inglês, e [neste tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript), tem uma solução muito simples por meio de um objeto chamado **URLSearchParams**

A utilização é a seguinte:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');

console.log(myParam)
```

O objeto é instanciado com o **window.location.search**, que entrega tudo após a interrogação da URL

E por fim utilizando o método **get** pelo nome do parâmetro como argumento, você consegue receber o valor do mesmo

A ressalva é que com esta abordagem parâmetros com chave como: filters[a], não entregam o valor correto através do get

Porém para grande parte dos casos, creio que esta é uma excelente forma de resgatar os valores dos mesmos

Answer (score 2):

```
function getUrlVars(){
 var vars = [], hash;
 var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
 for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
 {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
 }
 return vars;
}
```

Usei assim:

- `getUrlVars()["tipo"]` retorna `"1"`
- `getUrlVars()["nome"]` retorna `"po%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20cura"`

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a maioria das pessoas que procuram a resposta dessa pergunta estarão em um contexto de um web browser.

Mas para quem estiver utilizando node.js vale lembrar que [existe uma função nativa para isso](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options):

```
> querystring.parse('tipo=1&nome=po%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20cura')
{ tipo: '1', nome: 'poção de cura' }
```

Answer (score -2):

querystring = (window.location.href).substring( window.location.href).search("novaos.php?")+11, 100);

Supondo que o nome da minha pagina é "novaos.php". É só reindcrever de acordo com a sua.