# Como manter valores nos inputs com JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5

Boa tarde,

Em uma página php, tenho vários campos de input tipo texto.
Nessa página preencho cada input com um valor, 2,00, 3,00...
Como faço para que esse valores se mantenham nos campos, no inputs, mesmo que eu vá para outra página? Pois na outra página "puxarei" esse valores para fazer cálculos com eles.
Cada input tem um id, é claro, e estou declarado-os como global "window.varivel".
Não estou salvando os valores dos inputs em banco, pois eles, simplesmente, devem, podem ser alterados a qualquer momento, como uma célula de excel.

Comment: Estou apertado de tempo mas podes fazer isso via query string que passas de uma página para outra: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/429/129

Comment: Desculpe @Sergio, mas não entendi.

Answer (score 1):

Uma sugestão é usares uma *query string*. Ou seja parametros passados na URL como um GET.

Numa primeira fase juntas os IDs e seus valores em pares `id=valor` e concatenados com `&`:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    var queryString = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        queryString.push(inputs[i].id + '=' + inputs[i].value);
    }
    window.location = 'http://sergiofrilans.se/test/teste_SOpt.html?' + queryString.join('&');
})
```

e numa segunda fase lês essa string para poderes recuperar os valores.

```
var qs = location.search.slice(1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {
    var keyValue = qs[i].split('=');
    document.getElementById(keyValue[0]).value = keyValue[1];
}
```

O jsFiddle e outros "sandbox" impedem exemplos com `window.location` por isso fiz um exemplo online no meu site [que se pode testar aqui](http://sergiofrilans.se/test/teste_SOpt.html). Se alguem souber de outro fiddle/bin diga para poder pôr lá.

Comment: Essa é a melhor forma?

Comment: @GustavoSevero depende da quantidade de dados e do nível de segurança que precisas. Esta é a mais simples. Mais complexas e que não mostram a informação passam por usar o sevidor ou local storage/indexDB.

Comment: O que vai no lugar de "button" e "click" no seu código assim? Pois não quero clicar em nada pra fazer isso, ou melhor, não gostaria de ter que clicar em nada, só vou clicar no link para ir para a outra página onde vou usar os dados.

Comment: @GustavoSevero muda `document.querySelector('button')` para selecionar o teu link. Se fôr mais que um tens de ter um ciclo `for`. Se quiseres um exemplo mais claro tens de colocar o teu HTML.

Comment: Não, é um link só, se a ele que te referes em eu ter mais de um.

Comment: E desculpe a minha ignorância, mas como selecionar o meu link no lugar de "document.querySelector('button')"?

Comment: @GustavoSevero sem saber como o teu HTML é não posso ajudar muito. Arranja um seletor que funcione para esse link. Se tiver ID ou classe ainda melhor. Por exemplo: `document.querySelector('.classe_do_pai_do_link a')`. E tens de usar `.preventDefault()` para o redirect ser com a query string.

Comment: Certo. Porém meu link não tem classe nem id, é um link <a href="link">link</a>

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24398/discussion-between-sergio-and-gustavosevero).

Comment: @GustavoSevero ^