# Pegar informações a partir da url

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso pegar informações através de uma URL, como esta abaixo:

`http://www.meusite.com/?primeiro=11111&segundo=222222&terceiro=3333333333`

Eu queria pegar as informações do "**primeiro**", do "**segundo**" e do "**teceiro**". E talvez sei lá, outra que eu poderia colocar, exemplo "*quarto*".

Ah e também queria identificar qual eu peguei, ou seja, tipo assim:

[image: um alert como exemplo]

Comment: Seria algo do tipo? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-ler-valores-da-url-em-javascript-querystring

Answer (score 0):

Opa! Como vai?
Você pode usar PHP:

```
<?php 
$primeiro = $_GET['primeiro']
$segundo = $_GET['segundo']
?>
```

assim, toda vez que você atualizar a página enviando os parâmetros, o php irá capturá-los.
Não entendo muito de PHP, então um material bacana seria olhar o w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
Lá tem bastante coisa do tipo.
Espero de alguma forma ter ajudado.

Comment: Desculpa, mas você não tem a força.

Comment: :( 
Estou aprendendo o caminho do lado (sombrio) da força. Assim poderei finalizar o que meu avô começou.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, acredito que a sua URL está mal formada, você deve iniciar a sua queryString com o caracter <kbd>`?`</kbd>, então temos a seguinte URL:

```
http://www.meusite.com/?primeiro=11111&segundo=222222&terceiro=3333333333
```

agora vamos a segunda parte, ler esta URL, para tal você pode inicializar um Objeto URL.

```
var urlAsString = "http://www.meusite.com/?primeiro=11111&segundo=222222&terceiro=3333333333";
var url = new URL(urlAsString);
```

Se você fizer um `console.log(json)`, você verá que o mesmo possui alguns propriedades que você pode utilizar, segue a lista de todas as propriedades e os seus valores:

```
hash: ""
host: "www.meusite.com"
hostname: "www.meusite.com"
href: "http://www.meusite.com/?primeiro=11111&segundo=222222&terceiro=3333333333"
origin: "http://www.meusite.com"
password: ""
pathname: "/"
port: ""
protocol: "http:"
search: "?primeiro=11111&segundo=222222&terceiro=3333333333"
username: ""
```

preciso nem dizer que você terá de fazer uso do `url.search`, você até pode fazer uso da API [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) para ler os parametros, porém ela é bem recente e portanto não é suportada por muitos browsers, neste caso te aconselho à usar o seguinte codigo (com estrutura similar e compartivel, apesar de não implementar todos os métodos).

```
var URLSearch = function (search) {
  var that = this;
  this.entries = {};

  var start = search[0] == "?" ? 1 : 0;
  var params = search.substring(start).split("&");
  params.forEach(function (str) {
    var array = str.split("="); 
    var prop = array[0];
    var value = array[1];
    that.entries[prop] = value;
  });
}

URLSearch.prototype.get = function (prop) {
  return this.entries[prop];
}

URLSearch.prototype.set = function (prop, value) {
  this.entries[prop] = value;
}

URLSearch.prototype.has = function (prop, value) {
  return this.entries[prop] ? true : false;
}

URLSearch.prototype.delete = function (prop, value) {
  delete this.entries[prop];
}

URLSearch.prototype.toString = function (prop, value) {
  var params = [];
  for (var key in this.entries) {
    params.push(key + "=" + this.entries[key]);    
  } 
  console.log();
  return params.join("&");
}

var params = new URLSearch(url.search);
```

agora a um exemplo completo:

```js
var URLSearch = function (search) {
  var that = this;
  this.entries = {};
  
  var start = search[0] == "?" ? 1 : 0;
  var params = search.substring(start).split("&");
  params.forEach(function (str) {
    var array = str.split("="); 
    var prop = array[0];
    var value = array[1];
    that.entries[prop] = value;
  });
}

URLSearch.prototype.get = function (prop) {
  return this.entries[prop];
}

URLSearch.prototype.set = function (prop, value) {
  this.entries[prop] = value;
}

URLSearch.prototype.has = function (prop, value) {
  return this.entries[prop] ? true : false;
}

URLSearch.prototype.delete = function (prop, value) {
  delete this.entries[prop];
}

URLSearch.prototype.toString = function (prop, value) {
  var params = [];
  for (var key in this.entries) {
    params.push(key + "=" + this.entries[key]);    
  } 
  console.log();
  return params.join("&");
}

// para pegar a URL atual, utilize `window.location.href`.
// var urlAsString = window.location.href;
var urlAsString = "http://www.meusite.com/?primeiro=11111&segundo=222222&terceiro=3333333333";
var url = new URL(urlAsString);

var params = new URLSearch(url.search);
console.log(params.entries);        // Object {primeiro: "11111", segundo: "222222", terceiro: "3333333333"}
console.log(params.get("segundo")); // 222222
console.log(params.toString());     // primeiro=11111&segundo=222222&terceiro=3333333333

params.set("quarto", 44444);
console.log(params.toString());     // primeiro=11111&segundo=222222&terceiro=3333333333&quarto=44444

params.delete("terceiro");
console.log(params.toString());     // primeiro=11111&segundo=222222&quarto=44444
```

**BONUS**

Realmente não sei o que está tentando fazer com os valores da queryString, mas se estiver pensando em criar uma Rota, aconselho olhar a seguinte blibioteca:

https://github.com/chrisdavies/rlite