# Ler URL e exibir variável e valor na página Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Tenho um link montado com váriaveis de um email marketing, ao clicar no link gostaria de passar algumas informações nele e exibí-las na outra página.

Ou seja, seria isso:

Exemplo de link: `www.siteexemplo.com.br?nome=gustavo?idade=12`

Ao clicar nesse link, a próxima página lerá a URL e exibir os dados:

```
Dados
Nome: Gustavo
Idade: 12
```

Se possível, em JavaScript.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como faço para ler valores da URL em Javascript (QueryString)?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-ler-valores-da-url-em-javascript-querystring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caro user62799,

Uma pesquisa rápida aqui mesmo no [stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) já nos possibilita encontramos uma série de respostas a essa questão. No entanto, particularmente prefiro a seguinte abordagem:

```
function $_GET(param) {
var vars = {};
window.location.href.replace( location.hash, '' ).replace( 
    /[?&]+([^=&]+)=?([^&]*)?/gi,
    function( m, key, value ) {
        vars[key] = value !== undefined ? value : '';
    }
);

if ( param ) {
    return vars[param] ? vars[param] : null;    
}
return vars;
```

}

Formas de uso:

```
var  nome = $_GET('nome'),
var idade = $_GET('idade'),
```

Ou de modo mais performático:

```
var $_GET = $_GET(),
     nome = $_GET['nome'],
    idade = $_GET['idade'];
```

Fonte: https://www.creativejuiz.fr/blog/en/javascript-en/read-url-get-parameters-with-javascript