# Converter uma query string com array em objeto com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, querystring

Olá :)

Eu tenho uma query string que gostaria de transformar em objeto, porém essa query string tem um array que esta convertido da seguinte maneira:

&meuArray[0]=17&meuArray[1]=1

Quando eu converto essa parte de volta para objeto ele não me retorna o array que eu preciso usar para trabalhar em outras situações do projeto, que seria:

```
meuArray(2)
meuArray {
0:17,
1:1
}
```

Mas sim:

```
meuArray[0]: "17"
meuArray[1]: "1"
```

A função que eu estou usando para converter a query string em objeto é:

```
export const convertQueryStringToObject = (query) => query && query.replace('?', '').split('&').reduce((obj, val) => {
    if (!val) return obj;
    if (val.includes('.')) {
        const interno = val.split('.').reduceRight((subObj, subVal, idx, arrName) => {
            if (arrName.length - 1 === idx) {
                const [name, value] = subVal.split('=');
                return ({ [name]: decodeURI(value) });
            }
            if (obj[subVal]) {
                return { ...obj, [subVal]: { ...obj[subVal], ...subObj } };
            }
            return { [subVal]: { ...subObj } };
        }, { obj });
        return { ...obj, ...interno };
    }
    const [name, value] = val.split('=');
    return { ...obj, [name]: value };
}, {});
```

O que eu posso fazer para melhorá-la e trazer o array formatado do jeito que eu preciso?

Comment: Das opções indicadas no link acima, eu usaria [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/474347/112052), que indica o uso de `URLSearchParams` (já possui um bom suporte da maioria dos browsers, exceto o finado IE - no caso específico deste, tem outras soluções lá, que podem servir também)

Comment: Mas se a ideia é só criar um objeto a partir dos parâmetros, pode ser simplemente `var params = new URLSearchParams('&meuArray[0]=17&meuArray[1]=1');` e depois `var obj = Object.fromEntries(params.entries());` para criar o objeto. Usar `reduce`, inclusive, é um exagero nesse caso (aliás, [na maioria dos casos é um exagero](/a/522809/112052), não entendo essa fixação em usar `reduce` pra tudo, até pra quando ele não é mais adequado...)